# Laravel Forge default site

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, forge

We use Laravel Forge on a Load Balancer to handle a lot of sites on there. We always had one of the sites as a default/catch-all when a domain is pointed at us with no site conf set. Recently, that site's SSL expired. Took us a little bit but we got it back. Ever since then though, it has stopped being the catch-all. So if a site isn't pointing right, the invalid domain gets redirected to the first site in the list.

Here's a nginx conf for a site that redirects to the first server in the list.

```
FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.accuproadvisors.com/before/*;

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include upstreams/www.accuproadvisors.com;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.accuproadvisors.com accuproaccounting.com;
    server_tokens off;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate
    # ssl_certificate_key

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.accuproadvisors.com-error.log error;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/www.accuproadvisors.com/server/*;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://1127640_app/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Handle Web Socket Connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.accuproadvisors.com/after/*;
```

We have a 000-catch-all file and it contains:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    root   /home/forge/catch-all;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    error_page 404  /404.html;

    location / { }

    # return 404;
}
```

The folder `/home/forge/catch-all` contains the default index.html that was always the default until the SSL expired. Anyone have any tips? Anything is appreciated. Thanks!